# Parsing namespaced XML using libxml-ruby

Tags: xml, ruby, xpath, libxml-ruby

I'm attempting to parse XML in the following format (from the European Central Bank data feed) using libxml-ruby:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gesmes:Envelope xmlns:gesmes="http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01" 
                 xmlns="http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref">
  <gesmes:subject>Reference rates</gesmes:subject>
  <gesmes:Sender>
    <gesmes:name>European Central Bank</gesmes:name>
  </gesmes:Sender>
  <Cube>
    <Cube time="2009-11-03">
      <Cube currency="USD" rate="1.4658"/>
      <Cube currency="JPY" rate="132.25"/>
      <Cube currency="BGN" rate="1.9558"/>
    </Cube>
  </Cube>
</gesmes:Envelope>
```

I'm loading the document as follows:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'xml/libxml'
doc = XML::Document.file('eurofxref-hist.xml')
```

But I'm struggling to come up with the correct namespace configuration to allow XPATH queries on the data.

I can extract all the `Cube` nodes using the following code:

```
doc.find("//*[local-name()='Cube']")
```

But given that both the parent node and child nodes are both called `Cube` this really doesn't help me iterate over just the parent nodes.  Perhaps I could modify this XPATH to only find those nodes with a `time` parameter?

My aim is to be able to extract all the `Cube` nodes which have a `time` attribute (i.e. `<Cube time="2009-11-03">`) so I can then extract the date and iterate over the exchange rates in the child `Cube` nodes.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

either of these will work:

```
/gesmes:Envelope/Cube/Cube - direct path from root
//Cube[@time] - all cube nodes (at any level) with a time attribute
```

---

Ok, this is tested and working

```
arrNS = ["xmlns:http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref", "gesmes:http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01"]
doc.find("//xmlns:Cube[@time]", arrNS)
```

Comment: Neither of these actually works, they return no nodes. I tried the first one myself initially to no avail.   Interestingly, if I remove all the namespacing and use a root tag of 'test' then '/test/Cube/Cube' does indeed work as expected.  Any ideas?

Comment: See edit above for working code.  Took a fair amount of trial and error to get

Comment: Aha!  Thanks for this.  I actually figured out a solution which I've just posted, but your solution saves me a link of code :)

Answer (score 0):

So I figured this out.  The root node defines two namespaces, one with a prefix, one without:

```
xmlns:gesmes="http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01
xmlns="http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref"
```

When a prefix is defined, you can quite easily reference the *prefix namespaced* names.  Using the XML from the original question, this XPATH:

```
/gesmes:Envelope/gesmes:subject
```

Will return "Reference rates".

Because the `Cube` nodes are not prefixed, we first need to define a namespace prefix for the global namespace.  This is how I achieved this:

```
doc = XML::Document.file('eurofxref-hist-test.xml')
context = XML::XPath::Context.new(doc)
context.register_namespace('euro', 'http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref')
```

Once this is defined, finding the Cube nodes with time attributes is trivial:

```
context.find("//euro:Cube[@time]").each {|node| .... }
```